# iPhone-SDK:Thumbnail images in iPhone view controller view

Tags: iphone

I have 8 images in my project which has 320 * 480 pixels(full screen image). I need to show all the images in thumbnail format in a view (same like how we see in built-in Cameral Roll). When user selects one, it should display that image with the same actual size (320 * 480) as background of my first view.

May i know how to achieve this? Could someone please help me on this?

thank you.

Anyone Please?

Priya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider incorporating the [`TTPhotoViewController`](https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20UI/Headers/TTPhotoViewController.h) from the Open Source [Three20](http://github.com/facebook/three20) library. It's essentially a work-alike for the image viewer in the Photos app. (There's also a lot of other good stuff in there.)

Comment: Thank you. But can i include that files in my project? Does it open license?

Comment: I also have an idea from a person that i can have a thumbnail kind of button(s) with image(s) in the background, which will suit for developing such concept.

Comment: can i add title  for each thumb through Three20 api

Comment: Like the Photos app, the thumbnail grid doesn't display captions. But you can provide captions, and they will be seen in the full-screen view.